# How to exclude Code snippets from Microsoft Words spell check

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

I am writing on an computer scientific report and I'm really tired of Word 2010 always switching between languages (code in english, text in german) and marking all my code red just because there are some words it doesn't know.

So how can I turn off Word 2010's spell check partly for my Code snippets.

I would also appreciate solutions like a new dictionary or so.

Thank you.

@RandomA this is what I mean:

[image: Microsoft Word spell check on code snippets]

Comment: I know the tags do not really match, but I did not found any better... I hope you'll excuse that.

Comment: That seems a little weird, are you sure about this? From what I know, Microsoft Words spell checkers are extremely careful with red marking. It has a very high precision, but in normal circumstances, it will not attempt to get better recall at the cost of causing any annoyance to users. I think most people are 'ok' with it. I think they can raise the f-measure up if they want by various way to boost recall, but they want to keep people happy, so recall is kept at where it is just enough.

Comment: @Ben The fact that you couldn't find any tags that were really appropriate to your question is a big hint that your question is [off-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I've flagged it for migration to [su].

Comment: @David Richerby Ok Thank You I thought other computer scientists may also have the same problems...

Comment: @randomA see my edit, this is what I mean whith red marking of code snippets. And after that snippet the language wil switch to english and still I have to copy it into the dictionary. Isn't there a way to give Word a hint not to check that?

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Computer scientists tend to use LaTeX rather than MS Word so maybe it doesn't come up for us so much. :-)

Comment: @Ben Good for you. I didn't know you would accept a solution like the one you had below. I already think of some thing like that, but you have confirmed what I thought. Once you did that, I am sure Ms Words will not have any parameter settings near anywhere that would cause a problem. The settings are technicality, but I am sure you can do it in a much easier way like a mnemonic or short cut.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. I just created a new style sheet and then excluded it from spell check.

Right click on style: Edit → Style → Language → Do not spell check